# Using filewatcher to send files to specific folders

Tags: c#, winforms

Having a Form with only a comboBox:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h16ny.png)

And a `MyTest` folder in drive D where you can find `Folder1`,`Folder2`,`Folder3`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dClQx.png)

I want to watch any added `.txt` files in the folder `MyTest` and move them to the `Folder1` if `Folder1` is selected in the comboBox a.s.o.

```
 public void CreateFileWatcher(string path)
        {
        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher("D:\\MyTest");

        fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
            | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        fsw.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        fsw.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);

        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }

    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private static void OnError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("The FileSystemWatcher has detected an error");

        if (e.GetException().GetType() == typeof(InternalBufferOverflowException))
        {
           Console.WriteLine(("The file system watcher experienced an internal buffer overflow: " + e.GetException().Message));
        }
    }
```

Comment: It could work, so do you encounter an issue ?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it.Should I use `File.Move` and `comboBox1.SelectedIndex` in someway?

Comment: Hint: check the properties of `FileSystemEventArgs`

Comment: Also, read the documentation of `File.Move`. It's used to physically move a file from one directory to another. A ComboBox is not a directory.

Comment: Il edit my question because I guess people did not understand what I meant

Comment: also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19fc31ss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `OnChanged` event like below:

```
private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string destFolder = Path.Combine(@"d:\", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    if (!Directory.Exists(destFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
    }
    string destFileName = Path.Combine(destFolder, new FileInfo(e.FullPath).Name);
    try
    {
        File.Move(e.FullPath, destFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File move operation error:" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you move file as

```
string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Public\public\test.txt";
    string destinationFile = @"C:\Users\Public\private\test.txt";

    // To move a file or folder to a new location:
    System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);

    // To move an entire directory. To programmatically modify or combine
    // path strings, use the System.IO.Path class.
    System.IO.Directory.Move(@"C:\Users\Public\public\test\", @"C:\Users\Public\private");
}
```